# Is there anyway to get the size of the text in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

The title pretty much says it all. What I **don't** mean is how to get the size of the `JTextArea`. I need to get the size of the actual text. I am completely open to suggestions though. If you have a wonky workaround that involves using something other than `JTextArea` but still has a similar effect, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Change the `Font` size [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922360/how-to-preserve-command-prompts-formatting-inside-a-jtextarea-or-some-other-ty/25922802#25922802), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756612/java-swing-jtextarea-not-working/41756681#41756681)

Comment: What size? the Font size, the number of chars, the size in pixels or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the size of the `Font` then you can use:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
Font font = area.getFont();
int fontSize = font.getSize();
```

Alternatively if you set the font of the text area yourself you'll know before hand what the font size is, for example:

```
Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12);
area.setFont(font);
```

And if that wasn't actually the question and instead you want to know how big certain parts of the font are in pixels you can use a `FontMetrics` object for the font.

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = area.getFontMetrics(font);
```

Using the `FontMetrics` object you should be able to find out everything related to the size and distances in a font. You can find more information on how you can use the `FontMetrics` object here: [Javanotes, Measuring Text](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c13/s2.html).

I hope this helps :)

Note: This applies to Swing, if you're using a different kind of TextArea the answer will be different.