# Using ActionListener to Read a File Into a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, file-io, actionlistener, jtextarea

I want to create a `JTextArea` in a Java Swing frame that reads the contents of a file when I click on a button. I created a `JButton`, the text area and added an `ActionListener` for the button, but I don't know how to make the `actionPerformed` method to read the file after clicking the button.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton btn;
    JTextArea jtxt = new JTextArea(50, 50);

    public JavaGui() {
        super("This is the Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn = new JButton("Click Here");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn);
        add(jtxt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Open file for reading content
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println(file.nextLine());

        //Create the JFrame window
        JavaGui obj = new JavaGui();
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(500, 500);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // how to do this? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you struggling? You see, there are many good resources out there explaining how to read a file in Java for example. Or that explain how to push text into a text area.

Comment: So, you have, maybe, two questions, although I can distill down one.  First, how to read the contents of a file and second, how to append or set text of a text area.  You should maybe take a little bit of time looking into how those things get done as seperate concepts, allowing for the fact that a `JTextArea` is going to want a `String` of text

Comment: Now, having said all that, and you can be forgiven if your didn't know this, but `JTextArea` can actually read the contents of a file directly  - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756612/java-swing-jtextarea-not-working/41756681#41756681)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380 for a working example that reads and writes to a file.

Comment: And note: coming here, dumping your question, to then walk away, and not being around to respond to comments in a timely manner is also not appreciated around here. This is not a "drop your homework assignment, and come back next day to pick up the results" service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    if( e.getSource() == btn ) // your button 
    {
        doAction();
    }
}
```

`doAction()` contains the logic you need to run when you click on the button reference `btn`

```
void doAction()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try( BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader( Paths.get( "filename.txt" ) ) )
    {
        String line;
        while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
        {
            sb.append( line ).append( "\n" );
        }
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        System.err.format( "IOException: %s%n", e );
    }
    jtxt.setText( sb.toString() );
}
```